# How to execute WinSCP commands from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, sftp, winscp

I wanna know if there is a way to run WinSCP commands like `open sftp...`, from a batch file, without having to enter commands after WinSCP opens up.

Here's what I wanna happen:

1. I create a batch file (say `demo.bat`) that opens WinSCP command-line.
2. I insert WinSCP commands (`open`, `get`, `put`, etc.) in `demo.bat`.
3. The batch file `demo.bat` opens up WinSCP command-line and executes the commands (`get`, `put`, etc.) automatically.

Comment: WinSCP even has an option to create such a batch file for you: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`/command` or `/script` command-line switches](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting).

There's a [guide to automating file transfers to SFTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

A simple batch file using `/command` switch is like:

```
WinSCP.com ^
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "put C:\local\path\file.txt /remote/path/" ^
    "exit"
```

And WinSCP GUI can actually even [generate the batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script):

[image]